# How to Add Order Number, Order Date and Hour in a Woocommerce Email Template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-templates

I've been struggling for more than 4 days to customize my small WooCommerce shop email template by wanting to add the following requisites - order number, order date and hour when the order was mode.

This is the email template:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ) ); ?></p>
<p><?php esc_html_e( 'Your order №X from date X hour X was processed. You can track the delivery progress by clicking on the shipping number:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<blockquote><?php echo wpautop( wptexturize( make_clickable( $customer_note ) ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></blockquote>


<?php

/**
 * Show user-defined additional content - this is set in each email's settings.
 */
if ( $additional_content ) {
    echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( wptexturize( $additional_content ) ) );
}

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get values for your needs by following functions

```
// Get Order ID/Number
$order->get_id();
```

For Order Dates here are the multiple function with different dates you may use them

```
// Get Order Dates
$order->get_date_created();  //Order Created Date
$order->get_date_modified(); //Order Modified Date
$order->get_date_completed();//Order Completed Date
$order->get_date_paid();     //Order Paid Date
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: More information about Easily Get Order Info (total, items, etc) from $order Object @t https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion. 

I know it's silly but I don't know how to put the code into the sentence "Your order №X from date X hour X was processed"  without breaking it.

Comment: @PetarIvanov You may use it like this `<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Your order %1$s from date %2$s hour %3$s was processed. You can track the delivery progress by clicking on the shipping number:', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_id(), date('d-m-Y', strtotime( $order->get_date_created() ) ), date('H:i', strtotime( $order->get_date_created() ) ) );?></p>`

Comment: A hundred thanks! Do you only know how can the order number, date and number can be made in bold? Tried with <b></b> but it didn't work.

Comment: Just replace `esc_html__(` with `__(` and then add `<b></b>` or `<strong></strong>` around the `%1$s` and check, let me know if it helps

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks! Maybe I'm overstretching here asking for help but do you happen to know how can social icons be added linking to the social accounts? On a new row below the sentence "Follow us on the social media to be always updated:"

Comment: @PetarIvanov If you need further help then can you reach me out personally?

Comment: @KrunalPrajapati drop me a short email to petarivanov855@gmail.com, so your email doesn't get exposed here.

Comment: @PetarIvanov Done please check